# Net Core RedirectAction not working after using JavaScript on form onsubmit

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using JavaScript to on my form onsubmit.
It passes the data just fine on backend, but the redirect action on my controller doesn't seem to work afterwards

```
async function submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = document.getElementById('createAccountForm');
    var password = document.getElementById('user_password_input').value;
    if (!password) {
        var pworderrmsg = document.getElementById('pworderrormsg');
        pworderrmsg.textContent = "Please Enter a Valid Password!";
        pworderrmsg.style.display = 'block';
        return; // Form will not be submitted
    }
    //get the anti-forgery token
    // Retrieve the anti-forgery token value from the hidden input field
    var antiForgeryToken = document.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value;

    // Make a POST request to your .NET Core API
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'RequestVerificationToken': antiForgeryToken // Include the anti-forgery token in the headers
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username_or_email: document.getElementById('user_email_input').value,
            Password: password
        })
    };
    await fetch('/auth/createaccount',options )
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                console.log(response);
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(data => {
            alert(data.message);
            // Optionally, redirect or perform other actions upon successful account creation
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error.message);
            // Display a user-friendly error message or handle the error scenario appropriately
        });
}
```

then on my controller, I tried redirecting to a random page, just to test things

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

And nothing happens.

here is my form

```html
<form id="createAccountForm" onsubmit="return submitForm(event)">
                                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                //other stuffs
</form>
```

Comment: I think you should just redirect using javascript after submission.

Answer (score 0):

The fetch method return a redirect response. All you need is redirect to this response url. You could try following.
Controller

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Privacy", "Home");
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
<button onclick="call()">Fetch</button>
<script>
    async function call() {
        var response = await fetch('/home/test', {
            method: 'GET'
        }).catch(error => console.log('error', error));
        await console.log(response);
        window.location.href=response.url;
    }
</script>
```

Test
[image]